# Images in knitted pdfs are cut off

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to include plots in a knitted `Rmd` pdf document, but the plots always come out cropped. Here's a small example of what I'm experiencing:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r}
plot (cars)
```
```{r, fig.width=2}
plot (cars)
```
```{r, out.width='\\textwidth'}
plot (cars)
```
````

This Rmd produces a pdf that looks something like this (note the chopped off x axis labels):

[image: pdf output]

Any ideas what causes this?

Software info:

- knitr 1.23
- pandoc 2.7.2
- R 3.6.0

The call that compiles the document is

```
/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS rmdtest.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output rmdtest.tex --template /usr/lib/R/library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes'
```

Comment: It might be pandoc. I got pandoc 2.3.1 which is bundled with RStudio. Try an older version.

Comment: If you use `keep_tex: true` in your `pdf_document` YAML, you'll get a directory containing the PDF versions of the figures.  Do they have the labels cut off, or is it just when they are included in the document?

Comment: @user2554330: I tried it, the pdf figures already have their labels cut off.

Comment: I tried using a different graphics device now using `dev='postscript'` in the chunk options and it works! A bit messy, though.

Comment: It sounds as though your `pdf` device driver isn't working correctly.  You could check by using it to write one of those plots to a file without using R Markdown, e.g. `pdf("test.pdf"); plot(cars); dev.off()`.

Comment: Using just `pdf` works as expected, even if I call it in the same code chunk that produces the cut off plot.